# echo in php javascript variable single and double quotes

Tags: javascript, php, quotes

I know that's the stupid question but i don't get code to work...i would like to echo this in php:

```
<img title="vlc" id="vlc-playlist" src="./img/vlc.png" onclick="window.location='vlc.php?user=test&pass=testpass&type=vlc'">
```

i im working with datatables jquery plugin so i need to put this img tag into $row[7].

my try to echo this is here:

```
$row[7] = '<img title="vlc" id="vlc-playlist" src="./img/vlc.png" onclick="window.location=vlc.php?user='.$row[1].'&pass='.$row[2].'&type=vlc">';
```

and i im getting this for output:

```
 <img title="vlc" id="vlc-playlist" src="./img/vlc.png" onclick="window.location=vlc.php?user=test&pass=testpass&type=vlc">
```

$row[1] = username
$row[2] = password

so how to put single quotes to get result like on the first example?

Many Thanks.

Comment: Worth noting that given the context of your output you should probably be making use of [`urlencode`](http://www.php.net/urlencode).

Comment: http://php.net/string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Escape the quote symbol with backslash:

```
$row[7] = '<img title="vlc" id="vlc-playlist" src="./img/vlc.png" onclick="window.location=\'vlc.php?user='.$row[1].'&pass='.$row[2].'&type=vlc\'">';
```

> Single quoted
>
> The simplest way to specify a string is to enclose it in single quotes
>   (the character ').
>
> To specify a literal single quote, escape it with a backslash (\).

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Comment: woow...this really works...i was not know that i need to add slash to that...now is working perfectly...:) Thank You

Answer (score 1):

Use the escape sequence `\'` to add a single quote to the string.

For better understanding, consider reading the manual: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php

Answer (score 0):

try this :

```
<?php
    echo "<img title=\"vlc\" id=\"vlc-playlist\" src=\"./img/vlc.png\" onclick=\"window.location='vlc.php?user=test&pass=testpass&type=vlc'\">\n";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to escape those single quotes

```
  $row[7] = '<img title="vlc" id="vlc-playlist" src="./img/vlc.png" onclick="window.location=vlc.php?user=\'.$row[1].'&pass='.$row[2].'&type=vlc\'">';
```